# Openlayers SetLayerIndex

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gis

I have two layers. Layer `A` and `B`. Index of Layer `A` is 1 and Index of Layer `B` is 2, 
but features of  layer `B` is under then  layer `A`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by the index of layer A is 1, which index? Generally, layers in OpenLayers are rendered in the order to which they are added to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index of the layer in the layers collection is not the same as the Z-index. See Layer.setZIndex() method, which is probably what you want.

Comment: When layer1.getZIndex()> layer2.getZIndex() then select feature controll on layer2 not working.